# How to unit test promise.all using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method `core` that make http call to get response i tried to mock `HttpRequest` responses so i can write unit test , In below code all the test cases are passed however its not reaching to actual code and fake the response so my coverage can be improved. 
Any idea what has implemented wrong ?

main.ts

```
export class OrderStatusApi <OrderStatusParam, OrderStatusResult> {
    function core(requestMethod) {
      let request = [requestMethod.http.makeRequest({
                url: {
                    name: "orderStatusApi",
                },
                body: {"request": {
                        "header": {
                            "CustomParams": {}
                        },
                        "memberInfo": {}
                    }},
                processResponse: async (_response: any): Promise<Interface.Core.ProcessResponse> => {
                    if (_response.response.header.statusList && Array.isArray(_response.response.header.statusList.status)) {
                        const emptyResponse = _response.response.header.statusList.status.filter((item: any) => {
                            return item.source === "LINKS" && item.statusDesc === "Orders Not Found";
                        });
                        if (emptyResponse.length > 0) {
                            throw {
                                statusCode: "0000",
                                statusDesc: emptyResponse[0].statusDesc,
                                refId: args.refId
                            };
                        } else {
                            return _response.response;
                        }
                    } else if (_response.response.header.statusCode === "0000") {
                        return _response.response;
                    } else {
                        throw _response.response.header;
                    }
                }

            })];
            return Promise.all(request);
        }
    }
}
```

main.spec.ts

```
 import { HttpRequest} from "./common-utils";
    import {OrderStatusApi} from "./main"
    it("it should get success response and call processResponse promise", async (done) => {
            const response = {
                "response": {
                    "header": {
                        "statusList": {
                            "status": [{source: "LINKS", statusDesc: "Orders Not Found"}]
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            const HttpResponse = spyOn<any>(HttpRequest.http, "makeRequest").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(response));
            const myPrivateSpy = spyOn<any>(Service, 'core').and.callThrough();
            let _Response:any;
             myPrivateSpy.call(Service, HttpResponse)
             .then(function(result: any){
             const request = [HttpResponse.makeRequest({
                 url: {name: "123", params: {}}, 
                 "body": {}, 
                 processResponse: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(response))})
                ]
             _Response = Promise.all(request);
             console.log(result);
            //  _Response = result
            expect(HttpResponse).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
            expect(_Response[0].response.header.statusList.status).toEqual([{source: "LINKS", statusDesc: "Orders Not Found"}]);   
            expect(Service.core).toHaveBeenCalled();    
            });   
             done();        
        });
```

Comment: Why *are* you using `Promise.all`? There's only ever a single promise in the array. Also it's not clear which part of this is actually supposed to be under test, you've so much mocking going on.

Comment: there is another call in promise.all that i removed it to reduced code for understanding

Comment: @jonrsharpe core functions should return http mock response so basically trying to test `processResponse` that is part of `makeRequest`

Comment: Your test so far doesn't make a lot of sense. You seem to be reimplementing the method under test and testing your new version. Think about this in three parts: 1. does `makeRequest` get called with the right configuration (you can easily create and inject a test double as the argument to `core`, you don't need to spy on *anything*); 2. does the `processResponse` function in those arguments do the right thing if you call it with a stubbed response; and 3. does `core` return the resulting promise?

Comment: @jonrsharpe wasted my whole day today for how to put that test together so that i get this test working , New to jasmine can you help me with example with my unit test. stubbedResponse that is `response` in the test is same what `processResponse` expect

Comment: just want to invoke core function that execute `processResponse` and return the stubbed data